# convert, round, and multiply/divide in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We're doing an overtime incentive where people can earn raffle tickets based on the number of extra hours they work. They earn one ticket for every seven hours of overtime they work. I've built an excel sheet that I can just import the total hours into to track this, but I'm having trouble with the "number of tickets earned" formula.

I have a column for the number of hours over 40 worked, then a column to convert the hours to a number then divide by seven using: `=((C2-INT(C2))*24)/7`. Next column, I have `=ROUNDDOWN(D2, -0.5)` because if they worked 15 hours, it was giving them 2.5 tickets.

The issue I'm running into is that when they worked exactly 7 hours, I get 0 for the `=ROUNDDOWN(D2, -0.5)` formula. I tried `=ROUND(D18, -0.5)` but if they worked 6 hours 30 minutes, it gives them one ticket. I'm sure I'm probably missing something simple but is anyone able to help?

[image: spreadsheet example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already used `INT`, which would be a better option than `ROUND` or `ROUNDDOWN`.  Also `C2-INT(C2)` can be simplified to `MOD(C2,1)`:

```
=INT(24*MOD(C2,1)/7)
```

### Breaking it down:

> `MOD(C2,1)` take the decimal portion of C2 (i.e. Hours, less than 24)

> `24*MOD(C2,1)` convert from fraction-of-day to full hours

> `24*MOD(C2,1)/7` divide by 7.  For 6.5 this gives 0.928... and for 15 it gives 2.142...

> `INT(24*MOD(C2,1)/7)` take only the Integer part.  For 6.5 this gives `0`, for 15 it gives `2`

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it was something easy I was missing. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the `-0.5` argument of the `ROUNDDOWN` function. Why do you want to round to negative one half decimal places?

Just use `ROUNDDOWN(D2,0)`.

---

**Edit:** I'm not sure why `Agent 7` and `Agent 8` have different numbers of tickets if they both worked exactly 7 hours overtime. Is the `7:00` a rounded number?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming overtime is in column C, you could use:

```
=ROUND((HOUR(C1) + IF(MINUTE(C1)<30,0,1)) / 7, 0)
```

This should yield the correct number of tickets if you want to round up the hour when they are over 30 minutes. Otherwise, you could just take out the IF / MINUTE section and it will only count complete hours.